# Where do “‑ess” and “‑ine” suffixes come from?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, latin, germanic-languages, gender-positive

English has a lot of words in which the suffix *‑ess* makes a word feminine, such as *actress*, *hostess*, *huntress*.

That looks like a suffix that is also used frequently in Italian, so I’d guess it has Latin origins.  Are those all the same suffix?

*Heroine* uses what seems to be a Germanic suffix.  Are there any other instances of using a Germanic *‑ine* suffix to make a feminine version of something in English, or is *heroine* unique in this?

Are both these *‑ess* and *‑ine* suffixes still productive in English, or can we only use premade forms that somebody else already coined?

Comment: You'll notice I didn't ask whether a doctrine is a female doctor.

Comment: Did you try to find the etymology of the *-ine* suffix, or do some research already?

Comment: Since you're asking for other instances of that suffix, I'm closing this as "not constructive" because you're asking for a list. Can you please edit to clarify a more specific thing you're after and it can be reopened?

Comment: You're going to list the hundreds of words that end with an *-ine* suffix, like *dine,
fine,
line,
mine,
nine,
pine,
sine,
tine,
vine,
wine*, right?

Comment: @jwpat7 - They would not be suffixes though, right. They are parts of the word stem itself. Words like Imagine [Imag(e) + ine]

Comment: @Wolf5370, previous comment was facetious

Comment: When I posted this question it was about suffixes that make a word feminine, not about other suffixes that resemble it but mean something different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Executive Summary/TL;DR:** There are at least three different ***-ess*** suffixes involved here: one is for feminines of people and critters; one is to change adjectives into nouns of quality, the way English *-ness* does; and one that is used to create names of fabled or mythical lands.

Plus *heroine* for a female hero comes to us via Latin, not German, and the Latin is using the Greek *‑ine* suffix.  However, the homophonic word for the drug *heroin* did come to us via German.

Details follow.

---

### First *-ess* suffix < Fr. *-esse* < L. *-issa*

The *‑ess* that denotes female persons or animals derives from French  *‑esse*, from Common Romanic *‑essa* from Late Latin *‑issa*. Because it was in Common Romanic, it is no surprise that you should find it in Italian, Spanish, and Portuguese as well; for example, Spanish *princesa* and *poetisa*.

Adaptations of this form into English occurred at several stages of history, and not all prospered, as this entry from the OED shows:

> - ***‑ess***, suffix<sup>1</sup>, forming sbs. denoting female persons or
>     animals, is a. Fr. ‑*esse*:‑Com. Romanic ‑*essa*:‑late L. ‑*issa*, a. Gr.
>     ‑*ισσα* (:‑‑*ikyā*: cf. the OE. fem. agent‑suffix ‑*icge*: ‑*igjôn*)
>     occurring in class. Gr. only in *βασίλισσα* queen (f. *βασιλ‑εύς* king),
>     but after the analogy of this employed in several late formations, as
>     *βαλάνισσα* bathing‑woman, *πανδόκισσα* female innkeeper. A few of these (notably *διακόνισσα*, L. *diaconissa* deaconess) were adopted into late L. together with their correlative masculines, and many new derivatives of the same pattern were formed in Latin, whence they descended into the Romanic langs.; e.g. from *abbātem* abbot, was formed *abbātissa*, whence Fr.*abbesse* abbess. On the analogy of these the suffix became in Romanic the usual means of forming feminine derivatives expressing sex. In ME. many words in ‑*esse* were adopted from Fr., as *countess, duchess, hostess, lioness, mistress, princess,* and several which were formed on sbs. in ‑*ëor*, ‑*ier* (see **‑er**<sup>2</sup>), as *†devoureresse, enchantress,†espyouresse, sorceress.* In imitation of these the suffix was in 14th c. appended to Eng. agent‑nouns in *‑er*, as in Wyclif’s *dwelleresse, sleeress* (f. *sleer* = slayer), and to other native words, as in *goddess*. In 15th c.derivatives in *‑er* + *‑ess* gradually superseded the older Eng. fem. agent‑nouns in *‑ster* (OE. *‑estre*), which no longer had an exclusively feminine sense; subsequently the sbs. in *‑ster* (exc. *spinster*) came to be regarded as properly masc., and new feminines in *‑ess* were formed on them, as *seamstress, songstress*. By writers of 16th and succeeding centuries derivatives in *‑ess* were formed very freely; many of these are now obsolete or little used, the tendency of mod. usage being to treat the agent‑nouns in *‑er*, and the sbs. indicating profession or occupation, as of common gender, unless there be some special reason to the contrary. Of the words of Eng. formation still in current use, examples are *authoress, giantess,
>     Jewess, patroness, poetess, priestess, quakeress, tailoress.* In Eng. the
>     suffix is not used to form feminines of names of animals: *lioness, tigress* being adoptions from Fr. When *‑ess* is added to a sb. in *‑ter*, *‑tor*, the vowel before the *r* is usually elided, as in *actress, doctress, protectress, waitress;* the derivatives with ending *‑tress*, f. L. agent‑nouns in *‑tor*, have in most cases been suggested by, and may be regarded as virtual
>     adaptations of, the corresponding Fr. words in *‑trice:* ‑L. *‑trīcem*. The
>     substitution of *governess* (already in Caxton) for the earlier *governeresse*
>     f. *governor* was perh. due to false analogy with pairs of words like
>     *adulter‑er, ‑ess, cater‑er, ‑ess, sorcer‑er, ‑ess*; in *conqueress,
>     murderess, adventuress* the similar phenomenon is sufficiently explained by
>     phonetic reasons. The existence of such words, in which *‑ess* has the
>     appearance of being added directly to vbs., gave rise in the 17th. c. to
>     formations like *confectioness, entertainess, instructess*; but none of these
>     obtained general currency.

As you see, the issue is complicated.  Some of these *‑ess* words came via French and often Latin before that, but others were formed independently. Even English *actress* was probably formed separately from French *actrice* (cf. Spanish *actriz*, both from Latin *actrix, -ic-*), although occasionally *actrice* is found in English instead of *actress*.

I would say that this *‑ess* suffix is reasonably productive in English, at least insofar as that people would understand you if you coined something like *jaguaress* by analogy with *lioness* and *leopardess*.  I wouldn’t try *cheetess* < *cheetah* though, because people might think you meant something deriving from a *cheater*.

### Second *-ess* suffix < Fr. *-esse* < L. *-itia*

The second *‑ess* suffix is one for changing adjectives into nouns.  It is not a noun suffix like the first one.

> ***‑ess***, suffix<sup>2</sup>, ME. *‑esse*, in sbs. a. Fr., represents OF.
>   *‑esse, ‑ece*, = Pr. *‑ezza, ‑eza*, Sp. *‑eza*, It. *‑ezza* :‑L. *‑itia*, appended to
>   adjs. to form nouns of quality; examples are *duress, †humblesse, largess,
>   prowess, †richesse* (now *riches*). These words have been imitated in the
>   pseudo-archaic *idlesse*, but otherwise the suffix scarcely occurs as an Eng.
>   formative.

Words like *finesse*, *noblesse*, *politesse*, *tristesse* are direct borrowings from French, where the suffix was not to make feminine nouns, but rather the same thing  we use *-ness* for in English, so those correspond to *fineness*, *nobleness* (*nobility*), *politeness*, “**tristness*” (*sadness*) using the normal English *-ness* suffix.  The OED says of *finesse* in particular:

> Etymology: a. Fr. *finesse* = Pr. and Sp. *fineza*, Cat. *finesa*, Ital.*finezza* :‑Com. Rom. **finitia*, f. *fino* fine a. (Many of the early examples may belong to *fineness*; cf. the spellings *playnes, prophaness* for
>   *plainness, profaneness*.)

Words like *tristesse* are found in other Romance languages, like *tristeza* (sadness) in Spanish. 
I wouldn’t call it productive in English based on the OED saying that it scarcely occurs as a formative.
 I suppose you might get away with using them productively in English, provided you wanted to convey a snooty feel to it.

### Third *-ess* suffix < Fr. *-ois*

The fourth *‑esse* suffix is found in proper nouns like *Lyonesse* and *Westernesse*.   Both were Middle English names used in medieval chivalric romances.  This one  corresponds to the modern French *‑ois* suffix.  Of the former, [Wikipedia writes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyonesse):

> Lyonesse is an English *alteration* of French *Léoneis* or *Léonois* (earlier *Loönois*), a development of Lodonesia, the Latin name for Lothian in Scotland. Continental writers of Arthurian romances were often puzzled by the internal geography of Great Britain; thus it is that the author French *Prose Tristan* appears to place Léonois contiguous, by land, to Cornwall. In English adaptations of the French tales, Léonois, now "Lyonesse", becomes a kingdom wholly distinct from Lothian, and closely associated with the Cornish region, though its exact geographical location remained unspecified.

Presumably the formerly rare *Westernesse* was built by analogy on the same model as *Lyonesse*, but using *western* as a base.  The name appears in [King Horn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Horn), and was once rare.  However, J.R.R. Tolkien adopted it as a Common Tongue translation of his Atlantis calque, *Númenor*.   In his letter to Milton Waldman, published as #131 of his *Letters*, Tolkien writes:

> A name that Lewis derives from me and cannot be restrained from using, and mis-spelling as Numinor. Númenóre means in ‘Elvish’ simply Westernesse or Land in the West, and is not related to *numen* numinous, or *νούμενον*!

And in *Letter* #275 to W.H. Auden, he spells this out more explicitly:

> I have often used *Westernesse* as a translation. This is derived from rare Middle English *Westernesse* (known to me only in MS. C of *King Horn*) where the meaning is vague, but may be taken to mean ‘Western lands’ as distinct from the East inhabited by the Paynim and Saracens. Lewis took no part in ‘research into Númenor’.

Subsequent to publication of *The Lord of the Rings*, the word *Westernesse* has appeared [in print](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=westernesse&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#client=opera&rls=en&q=westernesse&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&psj=1&ei=r9tEUOrZCoONyAHFz4CQBg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=cc39281a480ea760&biw=1088&bih=721) much more often than it did in the 19<sup>th</sup> century, where it was only in reference to discussion of *King Horn*.   And Jack Vance took up *Lyonesse* and made it his own.

Probably because of Tolkien and Vance, more recent authors of fantasy (and of fantasy rôle-playing games) have used the *‑esse* suffix for similar constructions to create their own mythical lands, so in this regard alone might it be said to be productive.

---

### Epic Heroes and Heroines: *-ine* is Greek

Your supposition that *heroine* uses a Germanic suffix to form a feminine from *hero* turns out to be wrong.  Yes, German has such a suffix (e.g. *Königin* queen < *König* king) but that is not what is going on here.  Rather, *heroine* was but ‘recently’ adopted into English directly from the Latin, and thence from the Greek where it originated, as shown by the OED’s etymology entry for the word:

> Etymology: ad. L. *hērōīna, ‑īnē*, a. Gr. *ἡρωῑ́νη*, fem. of *ἥρως* hero: see *‑ine*. Cf. Fr. *héroïne* (16th c.). The Lat. form was also in Eng. use in 17th c.

So *‑ine* was a Greek suffix, and we got the Greek word via Latin.

Indeed, here are OED citations showing how *heroina* initially competed with *heroine*:

> - A. 1659 Cleveland *Mt. Ida* ᴠ, ― Next Pallas that brave Heroina came.
> - 1662 Evelyn *Chalcogr*. 61 ― A Sardonix which he cut, representing the head of that famous Heroine [Queen Elizabeth].
> - 1697 tr. *C’tess D’Aunoy’s Trav.* (1706) 85 ― To distinguish herself from among the Heroina’s of the most famous Ages.
> - 1725 Pope *Odyss.* xɪ. Argt., ― He sees the shades of the ancient heroines.
> - 1835 Thirlwall *Greece* I. v. 149 ― Medea seems··to have descended··from the rank of a goddess into that of a heroine.

The OED entry on this form of *-ine* is:

> ***-ine***, suffix<sup>3</sup>, forming sbs., repr. F. *‑ine*, L. *‑īna*, Gr. *‑ῑνη*, forming feminine titles, as in Gr. *ἡρωίνη*, L. *hērōīna*, F. *héroine* heroine. With this the Ger. *landgräfin, markgräfin*, Du. *landgravin, markgravin* (the suffix of which is orig. the same as **‑en**<sup>2</sup> 1), have fallen together in French and in Eng., as *landgravine, margravine*.

The only relationship between *‑ine* as a feminine and anything Germanic is the isolated word *vixen*, where the *‑en* was added to make the female fox.  The OED says of this form:

> ***-en***, suffix<sup>2</sup> :-WGer. ‑*innja*, repr. OTeut. ‑*inî*, occurs in several OE. fem. sbs., a few of which have survived into mod. Eng.
>
> 1. It is used to form feminines from sbs. denoting male persons or animals, as in OE. *gyden* goddess (f. god), *mynecen* nun (f. *munuc* monk), *wylfen* she-wolf (f. *wulf* wolf). The only surviving instance of this use is *vixen* female fox.
> 2. It is added in a few instances to the stem of a vb. or to that of a verbal-abstract sb., as in *burden* sb., *burian*, OE. *rǽden* condition.

I can find no direct connection between Germanic *‑en* for feminines and Greek *‑ine* for the sames, but perhaps it exists further back toward PIE.  The PIE gender situation is unclear; its feminine gender appears to have come into play a bit later. There seem to have been only masculine/animate vs neuter/inanimate originally.

In any event, I would not use *‑ine* as a productive suffix for forming feminines in English if I were you; you’ll get more traction out of using *‑ess* for that.

Comment: Excellent. I can think of only one other word which might contain the Greek *-ine* suffix: *chorine*, once in jocular use for chorus girls, otherwise *dansoozies* from the French.