# Where does the suffix "-tine" come from?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

Where does the suffix **-tine** come from? For e.g., *Ovaltine*, *Creatine*, etc. all have a *-tine* suffix. What is the meaning connoted to the noun attached?

Comment: Check this out http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80428/where-do-ess-and-ine-suffixes-come-from

Comment: @AndersonSilva that's a different *-ine* from Latin *-ina* rather than Latin *-inus*.

Comment: I don't consider this question a dupe.

Comment: Is this a topical question because Valentine's Day is coming soon?

Comment: Easily answered by Googling `etymology creatine`.

Answer (score 8):

It's not *-tine*, but rather *-ine*, from the Latin *-inus*, in turn from the Greek *-inos*, meaning "of", "pertaining to", "made from" or "similar to".

*Ovaltine* < *Ovomaltine* < *Ovo* (Latin: egg) + *malt* + *-ine*.

*Creatine* < *kreat-* (Greek: stem of *kreas*) + *-ine*.

Answer (score 2):

While Ovaltine is a brand (with an [interesting history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovaltine)) of health drink, the supplement [Creatine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatine), technically isn't in itself a brand. It's the name of an [amino acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid) which can help build muscle-mass. Furthermore, [proteins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein) are made up of combinations of amino acids. All these *-tines* and *-ines* lend an air of scientific reliability to brand names which like to tack them on at the end. That said, a number of these products do tend to be health-oriented and often actually are full of protein.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ine&allowed_in_frame=0) provides the following explanation for the *-ine* suffix often seen in Chemistry:

> **chemical suffix**, sometimes -in, though modern use distinguishes them; early 19c., from French -ine, from Latin -ina, fem. form of suffix used to form adjectives from nouns. In French **commonly used to form words for derived substances**, hence its extended use in chemistry.